# Solutions for exporting a remote desktop app (display and audio)

Tags: vpn, remote-desktop, vnc, x11, audio

I'm looking for a solution that will allow me to export a desktop app running on a server to a client machine. The server is ideally Linux, the desktop is Windows (+Mac for icing on the cake). The export should be encrypted and I need to support multiple clients from one server. I only want to export an individual app, not a whole desktop, and ideally am looking for open source solutions.

The obvious, cheapest, simplest choice is to use X tunnelled over ssh (e.g using Xming on the desktop) but X doesn't support audio.

What are the alternatives? Or is there a way to support audio using X or in parallel to X?

Thanks

Comment: Define "export".

Comment: i believe Microsoft Terminal Services RemoteApp is what you are looking for but its not free

Answer (score 1):

Nomachine's [NX](http://www.nomachine.com/products.php) supports sound tunneling in applications which can use Esound.  Here's the [relevant article](http://www.nomachine.com/ar/view.php?ar_id=AR03D00355).

Answer (score 1):

IIRC [NoMachine](http://www.nomachine.com/) / [FreeNX](http://freenx.berlios.de/) has basic audio support - but the [x2go](http://www.x2go.org/) fork improves on this. The [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_remote_desktop_software) on remote desktop specifically lists which systems provide audio support.

BTW remote desktop is something completely different from VPN

Answer (score 0):

There are some efforts towards the PulseAudio server and ALSA support by NoMachines lately, according to [this page](http://www.nomachine.com/fr/view.php?id=FR07E01796) and [this one](http://www.nomachine.com/fr/view.php?id=FR06F02073). I am not sure about their exact current status, but these improvements definitely will make the sound transmission over the NX protocol much more transparent once implemented completely.